# How to check total number of available Permission Set in the org?

Tags: permission-sets

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_limits_general.htm&type=5) an org can have maximum 1000 Permission Sets.

I would like to know where/how to check how many Permission Sets are already utilized in the org and how many are remaining.

Thanks!

Regards,
Kamruz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query list all Permission Sets in your org that are not owned by a profile, which includes Permission Sets assigned to users directly or via Permission Set Groups, use `SELECT count(Id) FROM PermissionSet WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = False`

Considering that [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_limits_general.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Permission%20sets%3A%20maximum%20(created)) mentions `Permission sets: maximum (created) is 1000`,to get the remaining licenses, you can subtract the count of utilized licenses from 1000.

```
Integer  countOfUtilizedPermissionsets = Database.countQuery('SELECT count() FROM PermissionSet WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = False');
Integer remainingPermissionsets =1000 - countOfUtilizedPermissionsets;
system.debug('query result'+remainingPermissionsets);
```

Also see related [post](https://www.simplysfdc.com/2013/06/salesforce-permission-set-report.html?m=1)

Comment: Thank you @Swetha